# how to group all the data as fast as possible?

Tags: python, pandas

I have 4188006 rows of data. I want to group my data by its column `Code` value. And set the `Code` value as the key, the corresponding data as the value int0 a dict`.

The `_a_stock_basic_data` is my data:

```
    Code  date_time        open        high         low       close  \
0      000001.SZ 2007-03-01   19.000000   19.000000   18.100000   18.100000   
1      000002.SZ 2007-03-01   14.770000   14.800000   13.860000   14.010000   
2      000004.SZ 2007-03-01    6.000000    6.040000    5.810000    6.040000   
3      000005.SZ 2007-03-01    4.200000    4.280000    4.000000    4.040000   
4      000006.SZ 2007-03-01   13.050000   13.470000   12.910000   13.110000      
...          ...        ...         ...         ...         ...         ...   
88002  603989.SH 2015-06-30   44.950001   50.250000   41.520000   49.160000   
88003  603993.SH 2015-06-30   10.930000   12.500000   10.540000   12.360000   
88004  603997.SH 2015-06-30   21.400000   24.959999   20.549999   24.790001   
88005  603998.SH 2015-06-30   65.110001   65.110001   65.110001   65.110001   

             amt    volume  
0      418404992  22927500  
1      659624000  46246800  
2       23085800   3853070  
3      131162000  31942000  
4      251946000  19093500  
.... ....
88002  314528000   6933840  
88003  532364992  46215300  
88004  169784992   7503370  
88005          0         0  

[4188006 rows x 8 columns]
```

And my code is:

```
_a_stock_basic_data = pandas.concat(dfs)
_all_universe = set(all_universe.values.tolist())
for _code in _all_universe:
    _temp_data = _a_stock_basic_data[_a_stock_basic_data['Code']==_code]
    data[_code] = _temp_data[_temp_data.notnull()]
```

`_all_universe` contains `_a_stock_basic_data['Code']`. The length of `_all_universe` is about 2816, and the number of `for loop` is 2816, it costs a lot of time to complete the process.

So, I just wonder how to use high performance method to group these data. And I think multiprocessing is a choice, but I think share memory is its problem. And  I think as the data is more and more large, performance of code need take into consideration, otherwise, it will costs a lot. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Why not just `groupby` on `'Code'`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll show an example which I think will solve your problem. Below I make a dataframe with random elements, where the column `Code` will have duplicate values

```
a = pd.DataFrame({'a':np.arange(20), 'b':np.random.random(20), 'Code':np.random.random_integers(0, 10, 20)})
```

To group by the column `Code`, set it as index:

```
a.index = a['Code']
```

you can now use the index to access the data by the value of `Code`:

```
In : a.ix[8]
Out: 
    a         b  Code
Code                 
8   1  0.589938  8
8   3  0.030435  8
8  13  0.228775  8
8  14  0.329637  8
8  17  0.915402  8
```

Comment: it seem helpful, i may need to know its performance under big data. thank you!

Comment: I tried to modify the example with 4 million elements in each column instead of 20. It completes very quickly (~70 ms for the last line)

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried the pd.concat function? Here you can append arrays along an axis of your choice.

```
 pd.concat([data,_temp_data],axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
- dict(_a_stock_basic_data.groupby(['Code']).size()) 

## Number of occurences per code

- dict(_a_stock_basic_data.groupby(['Code'])['Column_you_want_to_Aggregate'].sum())  ## If you want to do an aggregation on a certain column
```

?